# Select specific nodes in XML with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I'm writing a function that loads and XML document and converts it to a CSV. Since I need only some values from the XML file, the goal i'm trying to achieve is to select only the nodes I'm interested in.

Here's my code:

```
      XDocument csvDocument = XDocument.Load(tempOutput);

        StringBuilder csvBuilder = new StringBuilder(1000);

        foreach (XElement node in csvDocument.Descendants("Sample"))
        {
            foreach (XElement innerNode in node.Elements())
            {
                        csvBuilder.AppendFormat("{0},", innerNode.Value);
                    }

                    csvBuilder.Remove(csvBuilder.Length -1, 1);

                    csvBuilder.AppendLine();
                }
                csvOut = csvBuilder.ToString();
```

But, in this way I'm selectin ALL the child nodes inside the "Sample" node.

In the XML, "Sample" tree is:

```
<Sample Type="Object" Class ="Sample">
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>10096</Name>
    <Type>2</Type>
    <Rep>0</Rep>
    <Selected>True</Selected>
    <Position>1</Position>
    <Pattern>0</Pattern>
   </Sample>
```

Code works flawlessly, but I need only "ID" and "Selected" to be selected and their values written inside the CSV file.

Could anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Thanks.

Comment: So what do you want to do, {ID},{Name}, and so on for every Sample object?

Answer (score 2):

Learn more about [Linq-to-xml here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). You're not *really* taking advantage of the 'linq-edness' of `XObject`s

```
var samples = csvDocument.Descendants("Sample")
                         .Select(el => new {
                             Id = el.Element("ID").Value,
                             Selected = el.Elemnt("Selected").Value
                         });
```

This creates for you an `IEnumerable<T>` where `'T'` is an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx) with the properties `Id` and `Selected`.
You can parse (`int.Parse` or `bool.Parse`) the Id and Selected values for type safety. But since you are simply writing to a `StringBuilder` object you may not care ...just an FYI.

The StringBuilder object can then be written as follows:

```
foreach (var sample in samples) {
    csvBuilder.AppendFormat(myFormattedString, sample.Id, sample.Selected);
}
```

The caveat to this is that your anonymous object and the `for-each` loop should be within the same scope. But there are ways around that if necessary.

As always, there is more than one way to skin a cat.

**Update**  ...in ref. to comment:

```
foreach (XElement node in csvDocument.Descendants("Sample"))
{
    foreach (XElement innerNode in node.Elements())
    {
        //    this logic assumes different formatting for values
        //    otherwise, change if statement to || each comparison
        if(innerNode.Name == "ID") {
            // append/format stringBuilder
            continue;
        }

        if(innerNode.Name == "Selected") {
            // append/format stringBuilder
            continue;
        }
    }

    csvBuilder.Remove(csvBuilder.Length -1, 1);

    csvBuilder.AppendLine();
}
```

Comment: Sure I'd have to try this way also. But I'd like to go the way I already coded. There should be a way to edit: foreach (XElement innerNode in node.Elements()) adding some rule to skip unwanted elements or taking only those i want.

Comment: In your `foreach` check the `innerNode` name and if it's not `ID` or `Selected` then skip over it?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks IAbstract! Your code works! Before I tried appending innerNode.Name to the foreach statement but it was giving me errors! Thanks again. Btw, Pete, I also tried that way, appening Skip property to the foreach statement but i had to do something wrong because it wasn't working. Could you post a working example please?