# Selecting specific child nodes in xml?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, linq

I have some XML that looks like this

```
    <SolutionString>
  <Solutions>
    <Solution>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Property>
        <Name>DriverSheave</Name>
        <Value>1VP34</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>DriverBushing</Name>
        <Value>
        </Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>DrivenSheave</Name>
        <Value>AK49</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>DrivenBushing</Name>
        <Value>
        </Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>Belt</Name>
        <Value>AX30</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>BeltQty</Name>
        <Value>1</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>ActualCenterDistance</Name>
        <Value>9.88</Value>
      </Property>
     <Property>
        <Name>ActualServiceFactor</Name>
        <Value>1.71</Value>
      </Property>
     <Property>
        <Name>ActualDrivenShaftSpeed</Name>
        <Value>745/1117</Value>
      </Property>
     <Property>
        <Name>Cost</Name>
        <Value>32.65</Value>
      </Property>
      <TechSpecs>
        <TurnsOpen>2.5/4.0</TurnsOpen>
        <HubLoad>55 lb. 'running' Hub Load</HubLoad>
        <Tension>1.93 lb. should deflect belt 0.15 in.</Tension>
      </TechSpecs>
      <Property>
        <Name>Comment1</Name>
        <Value>If Driver is 2.5 turns open Driven RPM=931 and CD=10.25 in. If Driver is 4.0 turns open Driven RPM=819 and CD=10.47 in.</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>Comment2</Name>
        <Value>Correct tension for this drive (1.93 lb. should deflect belt 0.15 in.) will have 55 lb. 'running' Hub Load</Value>
      </Property>
      <Interchanges>
        <Interchange>
          <DriverSheave />
          <DriverBushing />
          <DrivenSheave>BK55X7/8</DrivenSheave>
          <DrivenBushing>
          </DrivenBushing>
        </Interchange>
        <Interchange>
          <DriverSheave />
          <DriverBushing />
          <DrivenSheave>AK49H</DrivenSheave>
          <DrivenBushing>H</DrivenBushing>
        </Interchange>
        <Interchange>
          <DriverSheave />
          <DriverBushing />
          <DrivenSheave>BK55H</DrivenSheave>
          <DrivenBushing>H</DrivenBushing>
        </Interchange>
      </Interchanges>
    </Solution>
    <Solution>
```

For the property list value of 2, it selects both,

```
<Property>
    <Name>DrivenSheave</Name>
    <Value>AK49</Value>
  </Property>
```

as well as

```
 <Property>
    <Name>Comment2</Name>
    <Value>Correct tension for this drive (1.93 lb. should deflect belt 0.15 in.) will have 55 lb. 'running' Hub Load</Value>
  </Property>
```

i believe it to because of the break in the properties with `<techspecs>`

Im using code like this to load each ID and its properties into a combo box like this.

```
 var cat = solutions
    .Descendants("Solution")
    .Select(x => new
    {
        ID = (string)x.Element("ID"),
        Properties = x.Elements("Property").Select(p => new
        {
            Name = (string) p.Element("Name"),
            Value = (string) p.Element("Value")
        }).ToList()
    });

var items = cat
    .Select(s => new
    {
        ID = s.ID,
        Text = string.Format("{0}. {1}", s.ID,
        string.Join(", ", s.Properties
                           .Select(p => string.Format("{0} = {1}",
                               p.Name,
                               p.Value ?? "(null)"))))
    }).ToArray();
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(items);
```

The issue im running into is that for each `Solution` / ID there are 12 child `property`'s. I would like to be able to specify just 6 of them, so for example selecting the first one

```
<Property>
    <Name>DriverSheave</Name>
    <Value>1VP34</Value>
</Property>
```

the 3rd one, the 6th one ect, and skipping the others.

Ive look at this [Select specific nodes in XML with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723251/select-specific-nodes-in-xml-with-linq) but am unsure exactly how to implement this in my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var indexesToChoose = new List<int> {1, 2};

var cat = solutions
            .Descendants("Solution")
            .Select(x => new
            {
                ID = (string)x.Element("ID"),
                Properties = x.Elements("Property")
                    .Select((p, i) => new
                    {
                        Name = (string)p.Element("Name"),
                        Value = (string)p.Element("Value"),
                        idx = i
                    })
                    .Where(y => indexesToChoose.Contains(y.idx))
                    //.OrderBy(z => indexesToChoose.FindIndex(p => p == z.idx))
                    .ToList()
            });
```

Here first we creating list of indexes to choose, then during creation of each anonymous class instance we're enumerating them, and finally we're taking only those having indexes in `indexesToChoose`.

As a result - after execution of code above `Properties` field will contain only first and second `<Property>` elements from xml.

Comment: this looks perfect, so if i wanted 2, 7, 10 i would simply do 
`var indexesToChoose = new List<int>, {2, 7, 10};` the more im seeing Linq the more like and SQL statement its looking, im just trying to learn the formatting haha.

Comment: @AndrewKucenski yes, exactly.

Comment: if i put the ones i want in like this, `{7, 2, 10}` will that order them, or is that going to be a separate `.orderby ` ?

Comment: @AndrewKucenski Surely it will not order them, it is just filtering. If you need to use `indexesToChoose` as ordering sequence too, you can use something like `.OrderBy(z => indexesToChoose.FindIndex(p => p == z.idx))` before `.ToList()`

Comment: this worked wonderfully, however, i cut my XML off in my example pieces, but this XML has ID2, and then the same list of properties, then id3, and so your code got the right properties for ID1, but ID 2-10 are left blank because i assume that the properties in ID 2, would be {13,16,18} yadda yadda so my code does not look/grab future properties i assume i would need to do some form of reset on idx = i++ every ID iteration?

Comment: @AndrewKucenski oh, I've totally missed the fact your xml contains more than one solution element. Well, you can even get rid of external counter and instead use override of `IEnumerable.Select` passing not only element itself but also its index in sequence. See updated answer.

Comment: i just added `idx = (i < 11 ? i++ : i = 0)`

Comment: @AndrewKucenski well, it is one of approaches. But frankly, approach with `IEnumerable.Select` override having index as argument looks more elegant for me.

Comment: so as you've been basically a life saver the last couple of days I'm having a slight issue with the `.Where(y => indexesToChoose.Contains(y.idx))` for some reason its grabbing 2 different items, both which are i guess you would say "tagged" as number 2 in `var indexesToChoose = new List<int> {1, 2};` ill update the xml in the question and show where it happens. if you have any thoughts

Comment: @AndrewKucenski very simple issue, I suppose. In the updated example you have 12 `Property` elements, so since you're using resetting counter code `idx = (i < 11 ? i++ : i = 0)` - 12'th element is treated as zero again (so if you have zero index in `indexesToChoose` - you will get both). I suggest you just use `.Select((p, i)` override passing index and get rid of external indexing variable and possible problems it can bring.

Comment: perfect, should have fixed that when you brought it up originally haha.

Answer (score 1):

This answer will help you: [Getting Nth value with Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452934/getting-nth-value-with-linq)

```
var nthItem = items.Skip(n).First();
```

Comment: This looks like what i want but my Linq knowledge is shaky, where would i implement this piece of code?

Comment: im my code it would be like, `var nthitem = cat.skip(1).First();` ?

Comment: Yeah that should do the trick, once you have selected the solution, then you want to find it's n-th child. I'd suggest changing the name of your `cat` variable to `solution`